# Sorting in SQL: Oldest records, but no repeat value within x rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a queue of photos to be featured on the homepage of a photography site. Photographers tend to upload several dozen shots at once, meaning that editors selecting the best of the uploads are very likely to put several shots from the same photographer onto the queue one after the other. But we don't want one photographer to own the homepage for hours on end.

At the moment, we sort the queue manually so that it's in queued time order (FIFO) as far as possible, but with no two shots by the same photographer closer than five slots apart. We'd like to automate this.

I know we can do the sorting in PHP, but can we retrieve the queue in the right order with a single MySQL query?

The table structure looks something like this. We sort the queue by swapping the queued_time of two adjacent shots - hardly ideal, but it works:

```
homepage_queue
--------------
id INT NOT NULL
photo INT NOT NULL
queued_time INT NOT NULL

photos
------
id INT NOT NULL
photographer INT NOT NULL
```

A browse through related SO questions threw up this page, which seems to suggest that I need to emulate Oracle's LAG function: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/04/12/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=2

Especially when I consider that I need to look at the last five rows, that looks messy enough that I'm tempted to run away screaming and do it in PHP, but is there an easier way I'm missing?

We generally keep the queue stuffed out to a week, at an hour per photo, so we're talking about maybe 200 records at the outside.

There are bound to be some photos at the end of the queue that can't be sorted in a way that fulfils the "five apart" rule. That doesn't matter, because we'll likely run the job every 24hrs, and with a steady stream of uploads it's OK for the tail end of the queue to be a mess.

Comment: How are you managing the queue? From what I understand, you pick the top item from the queue and show it on your website for an hour. Then you pick the next item off the queue, show it for an hour. And so on. When you pick an item off the queue, does that involve deleting the record? If so, can't you just keep a record of the last 5 photographers that have been on the web site? Then, when you pick the top item off the queue, just do `WHERE photographer NOT IN (SELECT * FROM last_five_photographers)`? *[You do then have **two** queues to maintain, but using very simple queries.]*

Comment: @Dems That'd work as far as it goes, but we'd really like to have the queue sorted in advance at least a day out so we know what's coming up when. That allows us to re-arrange manually if need be, for example to get something spectacular on the homepage during prime time rather than when most of our audience is asleep.

Comment: It's actually not a simple constraint.  What will be next depends on what has gone before.  It's not something *(I believe)* a single query is going to solve.  You could, however, use this method to build your real queue, row by agonising row.  But then, if you only want to queue 24 photos, looping 24 times will not exactly be time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add another table to the mix, one that records the last 5 photographers to have appeared on your website.

Query to pick your next photo:

```
SELECT
  homepage_queue.photo
FROM
  homepage_queue
INNER JOIN
  photos
    ON photos.id = homepage_queue.photo
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT photographer, COUNT(*) AS occurances FROM last_five GROUP BY photographer) AS last_five
    ON last_five.photographer = photos.photographer
ORDER BY
  last_five.occurances ASC,
  homepage_queue.queued_time
LIMIT
  1
```

Once you've picked your photo:
- Store that value somewhere
- Delete the oldest entry from `last_five`
- Add a new entry to `last_five` relating to the new photo's photographer
- Delete the chosen photo from the queue

A little extra maintenance, but a solution that's relatively simple and maintains itself.

- If the queue is full of just two photographers, they'll alternate
- If a new photographer then uploads a few photos, they'll get priority
- The photographers with fewest occurances in the last 5 always get priority

**EDIT:**

This simplifies the problem by focussing only on `what's next?`

You can adapt this to generate a whole new queue by repeating the process 24 times in a loop.  Each itteration you push the `next photo` onto your new queue.

You could even generate that list of 24 photos once, then use single itterations each hour:
  - Remove one photo
  - Use this method to add one photo

Then you have a constant list of 24 photos, a method to always add "the right one" to the end of the list, and the ability to re-order that list of 24 at any time you like.

Answer (score 1):

Really, when you ask a question, you should provide some information about the data strucvture.  Let me assume that you have the following columns in the underlying table:

- Queue position
- Photographer
- Photo id

If so, the following will return one row per photographer, based on the first photo in the queue:

```
select q.*
from Queue q join
     (select PhotographerId, min(QueuePosition) as minQP
      from queue q
      group by PhotographerId
     ) qp
     on q.QueuePosition = minQP
order by q.QueuePosition
```

The following is the variation for your actual data:

```
select q.*
from Queue q join
     (select Photographer, min(QueuedTime) as minQT
      from HomePage_Queue hpq join
           Photos p
           on hpq.PhotoId = p.Id
      group by Photographer
     ) qp
     on q.QueuedTime= minQT
order by q.QueuedTime
```

This will work assuming that the QueuedTimes are unique.  If they are not, a bit more work would need to be done.

Comment: Sorry, yes - I realised that after I hist Submit, and was editing it in when you replied.

Comment: The queued times are indeed unique. Returning one row per photographer might enable someone to jump the queue, though: If photographers A-F all upload three homepage-worthy shots each, then photographer G uploads some, the first of his should come after the 18 from the other guys - not after they've each had a turn. We'd only want someone to jump the queue like that if it were necessary to fulfil the "five apart" rule.

Comment: @EdDaniel . . . When I originally read the question, I think I misunderstood the part about 5 apart -- I thought that was part of the process of creating the queue (the input) rather then the output.  You can probably do what you want with a quite complicated statement.  However, in almost any other dataase, you could use ranking functions which would greatly simplify the effort.